# MySQL: mysqld_safe works but unable to start mysql service, why?

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL 5.6.19 on a Centos 5 machine.

I removed the data dir and created a new one with:

```
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
```

When I run:

```
mysqld_safe &
```

all works fine, but when I try to start the service I get the following error:

```
Starting MySQL. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID
file   (/var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid).
```

and the error log shows:

```
140720 07:30:18 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
140720 07:30:19 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/localhost.localdomain.pid ended
```

All files in `/var/lib/mysql/` are owned by `mysql:mysql`. I tried putting `my.cnf` in different locations, namely `/etc/` `/usr/` `/var/lib/mysql/`.

Here is my.cnf:

```
[mysqld]

innodb_strict_mode = ON
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_compression_level = 9
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_thread_concurrency = 2

max_allowed_packet = 1G

tmp_table_size = 1G
max_heap_table_size = 1G

query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0

log_output = TABLE
slow_query_log = ON
log_error = mysql-error.log

skip-name-resolve
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely your new database misses the control users that are used by the OS to control MySQL server.

Comment: How do I fix that?

Comment: You can try to remove and reinstall the default CentOS package, and then dump the contents of the `mysql.user` table to a file, and then import it to the new database you have created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to SELinux. The SELinux permissions on the newly created directories were not set properly.

I discovered that by looking at `/var/log/messages`. It had entries like:

```
kernel: type=1400 audit(...): avc:  denied ...
```

To fix it I used:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/var/lib/mysql(/.*)?"

restorecon -Rv /var/lib/mysql
```

The first command was probably not necessary, since I got

```
/usr/sbin/semanage: File context for /var/lib/mysql(/.*)? already defined
```

The second command did the trick.